# mySQL Query: How to choose just one comment from post list?

Tags: mysql, date, join, select, greatest-n-per-group

**Table post:** 
id

**Table post_comments** 
id, post_id, comment, created_at

**REQUEST:**

```
SELECT * from post
left join post_comments on post_comments.post_id = post.id
```

This request return all of the comments for every post. 
How could I limit this query for return just a last comment only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to adress this top 1 per group question.

One method is to filter with a correlated subquery that returns the date of the latest comment for the current post:

```
select p.*, c.*
from post p
inner join post_comments c 
    on  c.post_id = p.id
    and c.created_at = (
        select max(c1.created_at) from post_comments c1 where c1.post_id = c.post_id
    )
```

I also like the anti-`left join` solution, that ensures that there is no other comment for the same post with a later creation date:

```
select p.*, c.*
from post p
inner join post_comments c on c.post_id = p.id
left join post_comments c1 on c1.post_id = p.id and c1.created_at > c.created_at
where c1.id is null
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I like your left join solution - It is very simple and efficiency. I mark your answer, appreciate you have helped me.

Comment: Welcome @esff! Glad that it helped.